# How to prevent jwt token from getting stolen from the mobile phone and misused?

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt, openid-connect

I have a web api and mobile app.

I'm using Oauth (openidconnect). When user invokes the login endpoint, the Oauth flow is triggered which eventually results in the jwt id token being received by the api server (from the auth server).

Assume that the jwt id token is sent to the mobile app by the app server (in the api response), so that the api remains stateless, and subsequent api requests can pass the jwt id token into the endpoint so that the api knows who the caller is.

How to prevent this jwt from being stolen from the mobile phone and misused?

Answer (score 3):

Because JWTs are used to identify the client, if one is stolen or compromised, an attacker has full access to the user’s account in the same way they would if the attacker had instead compromised the user’s username and password.

For instance, if an attacker gets ahold of your JWT, they could start sending requests to the server identifying themselves as you and do things like make service changes, user account updates, etc. Once an attacker has your JWT it is game over.

BUT, there is one thing that makes a stolen JWT slightly less bad than a stolen username and password: timing. Because JWTs can be configured to automatically expire after a set amount of time (a minute, an hour, a day, whatever), attackers can only use your JWT to access the service until it expires.

In theory, that sounds great, right? One of the ways token authentication is said to make authentication more “secure” is via short-lived tokens. That’s one of the core reasons token-based authentication has really taken off in recent years: you can automatically expire tokens and mitigate the risk of relying on forever-cached “stateless” tokens.

In the security world, after all, relying on cached data to make sensitive decisions like who can log into a service and what they can do is considered a bad thing. Because tokens are stateless and allow for some speed improvements over traditional session authentication, the only way in which they can remain somewhat “secure” is by limiting their lifespan so they don’t cause too much harm when compromised.

The only problem here is that if an attacker was able to steal your token in the first place, they’re likely able to do it once you get a new token as well. The most common ways this happens is by man-in-the-middling (MITM) your connection or getting access to the client or server directly. And unfortunately, in these scenarios, even the shortest-lived JWTs won’t help you at all.

In general, tokens should be treated like passwords and protected as such. They should never be publicly shared and should be kept in secure data stores. For browser-based applications, this means never storing your tokens in HTML5 Local Storage and instead storing tokens in server-side cookies that are not accessible to JavaScript.

In general, token-based authentication does not provide any additional security over typical session-based authentication relying on opaque session identifiers. While there are certainly a good number of use cases for token-based authentication, knowing how the technology works and where your weak spots are is essential.

Another interesting thing to consider is that in some cases, a stolen JWT can actually be worse than a stolen username and password.

Let’s pretend, for a moment, that your username and password have been compromised. In this scenario, if the app you’re logging into is protected with multi-factor authentication, an attacker needs to bypass additional identity proofing mechanisms in order to gain access to your account.

While guessing or brute-forcing a username and password is a very realistic scenario, being able to compromise a user’s mutli-factor authentication setup can be quite difficult. Bypassing factors like app-based authorization, SMS verification, face ID, touch ID, etc., is a significantly more challenging than guessing a user’s password.

Because of this, a compromised JWT can actually be a greater security risk than a compromised username and password. Imagine the scenario above where the app a user logs into is protected by multi-factor authentication. Once the user logs in and verifies themselves via multi-factor, they are assigned a JWT to prove who they are. If that JWT is stolen, the attacker no longer needs to bypass MFA directly (like they would have to if they only had the user’s username and password)—they can now directly make requests as the user without additional identity proofing. Quite a big risk.

Comment: What's the recommendation to securely store the jwt in a native mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

You can get more details on the security-related queries on this page from react-native [Documentation on security](https://reactnative.dev/docs/security)

For your query on storage of the JWT,
Keychain Services on iOS & Keystore on android are the prebuild solutions on the respective OS, for storing sensitive data. we can write your own API bridging these services or you can use existing packages like [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) for this purpose.